# Scrapy: async database request in spider middleware?

Tags: python, twisted, scrapy

**Preambule:**

I have a spider that stores its results in database. Then, to save some time and remote web-server resources I decided to not request items that are already in the database. Reading the docs I decided that a custom spider middleware is the best choice I have.

```
class SkipDupeMiddleware(object):
    process_spider_output(response, result, spider):
        for r in result:
            if isinstance(r, Request) and item_in_database(r.url):
                log.msg('Skip %s' % r.url)
            else:
                yield r
```

where `item_in_database` queries the db.

It also works great and saves a lot of time.

**Now the real issue:**

Later I read that using blocking database requests in non-blocking apps is not a good idea. I'm always up to *"do things right"* and decided to wrap all my db requests in `adbapi`

I have found recipes to use `adbapi` in *pipelines*, but is it possible to do that in middleware level? Middlewares are expected to return `BaseItem`, `Request` or `None`, but `adbapi` returns `twisted`'s `Deferred`, which later returns `Request` or `None`.

And now I'm stuck.

Comment: this problem is already solved using pipelines in other cases I know. If you still have db lag problems, you can build dynamic local indexes which you can update once they are parsed (so you have not memory problems in your server). Middleware will also be affected also by a quiet db-data availability.

Answer (score 3):

You can (and should) return a Deferred from a pipeline `process_item()` method.

Comment: I know about pipelines, the question was about middlewares

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK,

Scrapy is mostly synchronous. Only downloading of pages is done asynchronous, that's why requests have callbacks.

Pipelines and middleware are synchronous.

Comment: Actually, both pipeline methods and request callbacks can be asynchronous and return deferreds.

Answer (score 1):

The scrapy by default will not make duplicaterequest in a crawl by using a Duplicate-Filter(enalbedby default). The setting parameter DUPEFILTER_CLAS decide which filter to use
Its default value is: 'scrapy.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter'. In fact, it is only the
choice now.
If you want a persistent feature, you should set a JOBDIR. Then scrapy will stored accessted URL and load them (into filter's dict) in next running.

You can get some tip in here:
http://groups.google.com/group/scrapy-users/browse_thread/thread/56546e9fab7030f3

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue, I want to do some checks (includes db calls) in a spider for the first a few items and stop crawling if the checks are passed (I think if there are only a few requests, we can do them using blocking db connection).

There is an idea came to my mind: if scrapy spider is good in doing http requests to sites we scrape, let's do async db requests using the same mechanism. It must be easy to implement for databases those have REST API, like elasticsearch.

This is what I made for AWS S3:

```
from types import MethodType

import botocore.session
import treq
from scrapy import Request


class BotocoreRequest(Exception):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BotocoreRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.method = request.method
        # https://github.com/twisted/treq/issues/185
        self.url = request.url.replace('https://', 'http://')
        self.headers = dict(request.headers)
        self.body = request.body and request.body.read()


def _send_request(self, request_dict, operation_model):
    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
    raise BotocoreRequest(request=request)


class ScrapyAWSClient(object):
    def __init__(self, service, access_key, secret_key, region, timeout=30):
        session = botocore.session.get_session()
        session.set_credentials(
            access_key=access_key,
            secret_key=secret_key
        )
        self.client = session.create_client(service, region_name=region)
        endpoint = self.client._endpoint
        endpoint._send_request = MethodType(_send_request, endpoint)
        self.timeout = timeout

    def request(self, method, callback, meta, **kwargs):
        try:
            getattr(self.client, method)(**kwargs)
        except BotocoreRequest as e:
            return Request(
                method=e.method,
                url=e.url,
                body=e.body,
                headers=e.headers,
                meta=meta,
                callback=callback,
                dont_filter=True
            )
```

Spider:

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client = ScrapyAWSClient(
            service='s3',
            access_key='',
            secret_key='',
            region='your-region'
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        yield self.client.request(
            method='get_object',
            Bucket='my-s3-bucket',
            Key='my-key',
            callback=self.my_parser,
            meta={
                'handle_httpstatus_list': [200, 403]
            }
        )
```